# Parsing filenames with python's re module

Tags: python, regex, parsing, filenames

I'm developing video player which scans user's video files and tries to identify them from the filename. If the video is movie, I would like to get it's name and video's quality and if its a tv show I would like to get the show's name, season's number, episode's number and video's quality.

I googled some example filenames and made simple script which tries to get the information, but I'm having really hard time dealing with exceptions such as when there is episode's name before quality, when the file has tag like "PROPER" or if the user has put the videos's source like "BluRay" before quality.

I would really appreciate, if someone more skilled with regular expressions would give some help.

Thanks!

```python
import re
names = [
    "The.Newsroom.2012.S02E06.720p.HDTV.x264-KILLERS.mkv",
    "Breaking.Bad.S05E10.Buried.HDTV.XviD-AFG.avi",
    "Breaking.Bad.S05E10.Buried.720p.HDTV.x264-AFG.mkv", #Incorrectly nonHD
    "Dexter.S08E08.HDTV.XviD-AFG.avi",
    "Dexter.S08E07.1080p.HDTV.x264-QCF.mkv",
    "Dexter S08E07 720p HDTV x264-QCF.mkv",
    "The.Great.Gatsby.2013.BluRay.1080p.DTS.x264-CHD.mkv", #Incorrectly nonHD
    "The Forbidden Girl 2013 BRRIP Xvid AC3-BHRG.avi",
    "Pain.&.Gain.2013.720p.BluRay.DD5.1.x264-HiDt.mkv",
    "Band.of.Brothers.S01E02.Day.of.Days.DVDRip.XviD-AC3-BAGS.avi",
    "Dexter.S08E06.PROPER.720p.HDTV.x264-IMMERSE.mkv", #Incorrectly nonHD
    "Dexter S08E06 PROPER 720p HDTV x264-IMMERSE.mkv" #Incorrectly nonHD
]
for name in names:
    tv = re.findall(r"(.*?)[ |.]S([\d+]{1,2})E([\d+]{1,2})[ |.]([\d+]{3,4}p|)", name) #FIXME: Get quality also after "PROPER/EPTITLE/.."
    if len(tv)>0:
        print("---------- TV ----------")
        print("Show: "+tv[0][0].replace(".", " "))
        print("Season: "+str(int(tv[0][1])))
        print("Episode: "+str(int(tv[0][2])))
        print("Quality: "+(tv[0][3] if len(tv[0][3])>0 else "nonHD"))
    else:
        movie = re.findall(r"(.*?[ |.][\d+]{4})[ |.]([\d+]{3,4}p|)", name) #FIXME: Get quality also after "BluRay/HDTV/HDDVD/.."
        if len(movie)>0:
            print("--------- MOVIE --------")
            print("Title: "+movie[0][0].replace(".", " "))
            print("Quality: "+(movie[0][1] if len(movie[0][1])>0 else "nonHD"))
        else:
            print("error")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Josh mentioned, the `+` qualifier shouldn't be used with `{m,n}`.  `+` matches one or more of the re while `{m,n}` matches m to n repetitions greedily. (See: [re syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)).

He also made a good point to use [re.VERBOSE](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE) to with help readability for your regex.

EDIT: (thanks @eyguem for pointing this out) I may be wrong but your `[ |.]` is an attempt to match a space and a period?  If so, you don't need the `|` <strike>and it may be good habit to escape re special characters such as the `.`.  (i.e. `[ \.]`).</strike>

If you know the string between season/episode and quality are alphabets, spaces, or periods you can use something like this (EDIT: if there are non-alphabet characters like '-', '+', etc., you'll need to add them into the character set):

```
    tv = re.findall(r"""(.*)          # Title
                        [ .]
                        S(\d{1,2})    # Season
                        E(\d{1,2})    # Episode
                        [ .a-zA-Z]*  # Space, period, or words like PROPER/Buried
                        (\d{3,4}p)?   # Quality
                    """, name, re.VERBOSE)
```

Likewise, you can do this for the movie part:

```
movie = re.findall(r"""(.*?[ .]\d{4})  # Title including year
                       [ .a-zA-Z]*     # Space, period, or words
                       (\d{3,4}p)?      # Quality
                    """, name, re.VERBOSE)
```

This is the output:

```
---------- TV ----------
Show: The Newsroom 2012
Season: 2
Episode: 6
Quality: 720p
---------- TV ----------
Show: Breaking Bad
Season: 5
Episode: 10
Quality: nonHD
---------- TV ----------
Show: Breaking Bad
Season: 5
Episode: 10
Quality: 720p
---------- TV ----------
Show: Dexter
Season: 8
Episode: 8
Quality: nonHD
---------- TV ----------
Show: Dexter
Season: 8
Episode: 7
Quality: 1080p
---------- TV ----------
Show: Dexter
Season: 8
Episode: 7
Quality: 720p
--------- MOVIE --------
Title: The Great Gatsby 2013
Quality: 1080p
--------- MOVIE --------
Title: The Forbidden Girl 2013
Quality: nonHD
--------- MOVIE --------
Title: Pain & Gain 2013
Quality: 720p
---------- TV ----------
Show: Band of Brothers
Season: 1
Episode: 2
Quality: nonHD
---------- TV ----------
Show: Dexter
Season: 8
Episode: 6
Quality: 720p
---------- TV ----------
Show: Dexter
Season: 8
Episode: 6
Quality: 720p
```

Comment: Hello. Escaping the dot between brackets isn't necessary: the special characters loose their speciality when put between brackets meaning a set of characters for one position. So ``[.G]`` means "a dot or the letter G", not "any character or G"

Comment: For ``"Breaking.Bad.S05E10.Hard-Buried.720p.HDTV.x264-AFG.mkv"`` (with **-** character that isn't in ``[ .a-zA-Z]`` , the result will erroneously be **nonHD**. Maybe such a case or other similar one will never happen...

Comment: Thank you for your thanking, but there is no interest in my opinion to write it in your answer. - Also you shouldn't strike all the sentence out, the first part until ``and it may be good habit to escape ....`` is perfectly right.

Answer (score 1):

It might help if your regular expression was broken up using the re.VERBOSE flag.

I see

```
[\d+]{3,4}
```

and I think this is misleading. Doesn't this mean "three or four repetitions of at least one decimal"? I think

```
\d{3,4}
```

Is fine.

When developing regular expressions, I start by creating small patterns:

```
episode_pattern = re.compile(r"S\d+E\d+", re.IGNORECASE)
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`[ae*6]` represents ONE character. It means this character can be either `a` , either `e`, either `*` or `6`.
Then it isn't necessary to write `[ |.]` that, by the way , means "character being either , either `|`, or `.`".

I did some improvements. If you have questions, don't hesitate to ask me.

NB: the parts like this one: `(?:[ .](\d{3}\d?p)|\Z)`  after `.*?`
are necessary to force the lazy dot `.*?` to go to the next dot **.** followed by **720p** if there is one, not to stop at the first dot **.** and considering the digits and **p** are optional.
If there is no such **720p**, the lazy dot goes until the end of the string (`\Z` forces it to do so) and declares it didn't find any **720p**.

```
import re
names = [
    "The.Newsroom.2012.S02E06.720p.HDTV.x264-KILLERS.mkv",
    "Breaking.Bad.S05E10.Buried.HDTV.XviD-AFG.avi",
    "Trekking.Bad.S05E12.Buried.720p.HDTV.x264-AFG.mkv",
    "Dexter.S08E08.HDTV.XviD-AFG.avi",
    "Dexter.S08E07.1080p.HDTV.x264-QCF.mkv",
    "Dexter S08E07 720p HDTV x264-QCF.mkv",
    "The.Great.Gatsby.2013.BluRay.1080p.DTS.x264-CHD.mkv",
    "The Forbidden Girl 2013 BRRIP Xvid AC3-BHRG.avi",
    "Pain.&.Gain.2013.720p.BluRay.DD5.1.x264-HiDt.mkv",
    "Band.of.Brothers.S01E02.Day.of.Days.DVDRip.XviD-AC3-BAGS.avi",
    "Dexter.S08E06.PROPER.720p.HDTV.x264-IMMERSE.mkv",
    "Dexter S08E06 PROPER 720p HDTV x264-IMMERSE.mkv"
    ]

regtv = re.compile('(.+?)'
                   '[ .]S(\d\d?)E(\d\d?)'
                   '.*?'
                   '(?:[ .](\d{3}\d?p)|\Z)?')

regmovie = re.compile('(.*?[ .]\d{4})'
                      '.*?'
                      '(?:[ .](\d{3}\d?p)|\Z)?')

for name in names:
    tv = regtv.match(name)
    if tv:
        print("---------- TV ----------\n"
              "Show: %s\n"
              "Season: %s\n"
              "Episode: %s\n"
              "Quality: %s" %
              (tv.group(1).replace(".", " "),
               tv.group(2),
               tv.group(3),
               tv.group(4) if tv.group(4) else "nonHD")
              )
    else:
        movie = regmovie.match(name)
        if movie:
            print("--------- MOVIE --------\n"
                  "Title: %s\n"
                  "Quality: %s" %
                  (movie.group(1).replace(".", " "),
                   movie.group(2) if movie.group(2) else "nonHD")
                  )
        else:
            print("----- error for -----\n%s" % name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question says with "re module" but in the interest of being helpful instead of pedantic, here is a simpler, faster parsing for filenames.

```
file_name = path.rsplit('.', 1)[0].rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
```

If you need it to work for both windows and unix, add an rsplit('\', 1)[-1] at the end.  This is fast, predictable, and parses the file name every time.